# Selecting data from DB using LIMIT

Tags: php

I have a total of 5000 rows in my database. Now, what i want to achieve is, my supervisor script should be able to select 1000 at a time and a record selected before shouldn't be selected any longer.  I could achieve this by `toggling status` for a selected row but is there a way i can achieve this with LIMIT?

In the query below, i am selecting the data in batches of 1000. After the first 1000 rows is processed, the script must select another 1000 unique rows. Is there a way to achieve that with LIMITS ?

**Index.php**

```
 $sql = "select * from `table` where `crude_at` between '".$date_from."' 
 and '".$date_to."' LIMIT 1000";   
 $res  = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
     $no_of_counts = 0
    //do something for the selected rows here
    $no_of_counts++        
    if ($no_of_counts == '1000')
    {
        //fetch the next 1000 rows
    }
    }
```

Comment: You could use the offset, like `LIMIT 999, 1000`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @JayBlanchard, can you add some brief explanation how LIMIT 999,1000 would work ?

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/limit.html